# @Component annotation is not working

Tags: spring, security, components, autowired

Please advise where I am going wrong here.  @Component and @Qualifier is not working.  Getting No such bean defined exception.

I have spring security xml, a part of that is follows

```
<http use-expressions="true" create-session="stateless" >
<form-login login-page="/inventory/auth/login"
        always-use-default-target="true" default-target-url="/inventory/secureauth"         
        authentication-failure-url="/inventory/secureauth/login?login_error=1" 
        username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password" />

    <custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="cookieSessionFilter" />          
</http>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider ref="userAuthenticationProvider" />
</authentication-manager>
```

I wrote a AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter as follows

```
package com.eim.security;

@Component(value="cookieSessionFilter")
public class CookieSessionFilter extends AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter {

 @Autowired
public CookieSessionFilter(@Qualifier(value="authenticationManager") AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
    setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
}
```

Please find my spring dispatcher servlet xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd">
<context:annotation-config />
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<context:component-scan 
    base-package="com.eim.security, com.eim.glossary.controller">
</context:component-scan>
```

I am getting the following exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with     name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#9' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [9]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#9': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cookieSessionFilter' while setting constructor argument with key [2]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'cookieSessionFilter' is defined
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
```

Not sure why I am getting the below exception as I gave base-package for component scan to Spring container

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'cookieSessionFilter'
```

Kindly advise please

Comment: Spring Security detects beans in the root context (loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener`) your beans are loaded by the `DispatcherServlet`. Move the detection of the bean (or declare it explictly) in the root context.

Comment: Thanks for your advise.  Move the detection of the bean in the root context means?  Do you mean to update in web.xml?  Could you please advise me with example?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks lot M.Deinum

As per your advise, I have moved the detection of the bean in the root context by updating web.xml. It is working now.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml, WEB-INF/eimsgo-security.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Previously, I mentioned spring-servlet.xml at servlet level using .  Now moved to

Thanks!!

Comment: Well it works but you have now duplicated all of your beans. The `spring-servlet.xml` is now being loaded twice, probably not something you want. The generic available beans like services, daos, datasources etc. should be loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener` the web related things (controllers, view resolvers etc.) should be loaded by the `DispatcherServlet`.